# php code to python (corresponding functions) for encryption

Tags: python, php, encryption

so, i had this eariler but deleted, could someone tell me the corresponding functions in python that can give me what i need here. I understand all of this except for the encryption stuff, like i could use the random module in python to gen random bytes/strings. I can use datetime for time, but the other stuff, ive been looking for around an hour now with no luck, or if someone could just flat out convert this code that would be great. Thanks

Code tried so far
Note i am just trying to put 2 and 2 together, i cant find any modules that correspond with the php funcs. So i used rsa, but i just dont feel like that can be right. making the get returns the public key and the key id which is used in the encryption. I found the php off gituhb.

```
def randomchar(n):
    return "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters)for x in range(n))
headers = {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
            'accept-langauge': 'en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.7',
            'origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
            'referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'accept': '*/*',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }

r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/data/shared_data/', headers=headers)

dicts = r.json()

pubkey = dicts['public_key']
keyid = dicts['key_id']


realpubkey = b64decode(pubkey)

key = randomchar(32)
iv = randomchar(12)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
time = str(now.year)  + "-" + str(now.month) + "-" + str(now.day)

rsa.encrypt(key, realpubkey)
```

```
  public static function encryptPassword(
        $password,
        $publicKeyId,
        $publicKey)
    {
        $key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12);
        $time = time();

        openssl_public_encrypt($key ,$encryptedAesKey, base64_decode($publicKey));
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($password, 'aes-256-gcm', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag, strval($time));

        $payload = base64_encode("\x01" | pack('n', intval($publicKeyId)) . $iv . pack('s', strlen($encryptedAesKey)) . $encryptedAesKey . $tag . $encrypted);

        return sprintf('#PWD_INSTAGRAM:4:%s:%s', $time, $payload);
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!